# Amazon Athena takes all files from the direction instead of one file

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am writing a query to create a table on Amazon Athena that takes data from the files on the S3 directory. However, I would like to create a table from one file instead of all the files in the directory. [image]

I get a location error if I enter LOCATION 's3://influx-cold-storage/2018/file1.csv'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LOCATION keyword docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html) describes it's usage like so:

> Athena reads all files in an Amazon S3 location you specify in the CREATE TABLE statement, and cannot ignore any files included in the prefix. When you create tables, include in the Amazon S3 path only the files you want Athena to read. Use AWS Lambda functions to scan files in the source location, remove any empty files, and move unneeded files to another location.

And specifies that using exact paths to files and wildcards (such as *) is not an option..

You'll have to put whatever exact file you need in it's own directory.

I wrote a quick bash script that will move all files in the current directory to directories of the same name without an extension for a hacky workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "INFO - Moving all files in current directory to directory of same name."

for file in ./*; do
    [[ -d "$file" ]] && continue 
    fname=`basename $file`
    dname=${fname%.*}
    echo "INFO - Creating directory $dname"
    mkdir "$dname"
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "INFO - $dname created" || echo "WARN - $fname directory already exists."
    echo "INFO - Moving $fname to ${dname}/${fname}"
    mv "$file" "${dname}/${fname}"
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "INFO - $fname moved successfully." || echo "WARN - Possibly failed. Checkfor $fname in $dname directory."
done
```